# How to insert multiple users to user field in a list using sign in name in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to insert multiple users to a list field.I have an array,it contains data like below

```
[{"Login":"i:0#.f|membership|user1a@site.com","Name":"user1 name","Email":""},{"Login":"i:0#.f|membership|user2@site.com","Name":"user2 name","Email":""}]
```

This data set does not contain user ids.So how I get user Ids for these all users at a time.

I have a code, it's only getting one user at a time.
here is my code

```
var result = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.Utility.ResolvePrincipal(clientContext, clientContext.Web, emailAddress, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.PrincipalType.User, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.PrincipalSource.All, null, true);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        var user = clientContext.Web.EnsureUser(result.Value.LoginName);
                        clientContext.Load(user);
                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    }
```

Please tell me how to do this

Answer (score 2):

I just have the solution for you:

first of all, if i can understand your list field which will contain multiple users is a column "Person or Group" type isn't it ?

If it's YES then follow me:

**1-** First you need to get the SharePoint User information using a REST request

```
/sites/Support/_api/Web/SiteUsers/GetByEmail('Type the email here')
```

Once you get that, the body request will have the following informations:

- Metadata
- Id
- LoginName
- Title
- Email
- ...etc

**2-** Filter and get the user ***Id*** from the REST request body

**3-** Keep doing that for all the users you want to have, and append the results (the Ids) to an Array

**4-** The most important thing you need to understand that for the Person or Group field, if you want to Assign users to this field (let's name it **Persons**) you need to update the field named ***PersonsId***

> YES we did, SharePoint has added ***Id*** to the field name

**5-** By using a REST request:

**Method:** POST

**Uri:**

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Type list name here')/items(the ID of the item or the row in the list)
```

**Headers:**

```
{
  "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
  "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
  "IF-MATCH": "*",
  "X-Requestdigest": "xRequestDigest",
  "X-HTTP-Method": "PATCH"
}
```

**Body (JSON):**

```
  {
     '__metadata':{'type':'SP.Data.<List Name>ListItem'},
     'PersonsId': {
                  "__metadata": {
                                "type": "Collection(Edm.Int32)"
                                },
                                "results": [You array here] //for example [19,24]
                  }
  }
```

**6-** and voilà, the result (Column of type Person or Group updated using their Id returned by their emails)

[image]

I Hope this will help you, If you didn't understand please let me know, I will be happy to help you.

here is my linkedin: [Aimen Boulahia](https://www.linkedin.com/in/aimen-boulahia/) .

Good luck.

Comment: thanks alot for your reply.Actually I want to get all the users Ids in a single SP API call.According to your answer I have to call multiple times

Comment: alright, if you want to get all the users, you can quite simply get them all using REST api and the follwing endpoint:

Comment: /sites/Support/_api/Web/SiteUsers?$Select=Id

Comment: This site contains many users, I think more than 500.So all the users getting method is hard case

Comment: so what type of users you want to get ?

Comment: I have a form with CC field. It contains few users, I can't imagine users count,
I fixed this using  CSOM. But couldn't find a method to do this by single api call,I did it one by one.However thanks alot for your help